# Serial downvoting reversed

Tags: support, voting

what is `Serial downvoting reversed`?

I just got +14 Reputations from the event listed as `Serial downvoting reversed`.
[image: +14 Reputations from the event listed as Serial downvoting reversed]

What does that mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Stack Exchange system is very good at recognizing people who (for whatever reason) decide to trawl through someones Question or Answer list and either upvote or downvote repeatedly.

This is regarded as abusive behaviour and the system reverses this.

Thus look at the previous day reputation - you'll notice a number of your answers were downvoted over a short period of time.  The system recognized that this was down from one person and reversed the result.

[Additional community reliance for negative downvote reversal is also a component of a solution.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1311/how-to-defend-against-negative-incorrect-votes)  This was noted in another answer, but I, aking1012 the editor, didn't feel it merited another answer.