# I lost 3000+ rep as a reversal

Tags: support

It is possible that someone serially upvoted my posts. I can't see it.

But the weird thing is that some of my answers were unaccepted. That is a puzzle.

What does this mean?

Comment: Weirder: those unaccepted answers still have the tick, at least when I look at them.

Comment: Sounds like a big glitch.

Comment: It looks a glitch for me too.

Comment: I saw some people lost 20000+ today too.

Comment: @Pilot6 Have a link to these people that lost 20k+?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/users/260935/cl-netbox

Comment: You may want to read http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15520/169736

Comment: Holy smokes! I would not be happy if I lost 20k...

Comment: @AndroidDev Many more lost 20k, 17k, 10k.... I lost 500+ , 
http://askubuntu.com/users?page=8834&tab=reputation&filter=week     , ,  http://askubuntu.com/users?page=8833&tab=reputation&filter=week

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is in reaction to the issues raised in [Exchange votes or favours](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15317/exchange-votes-or-favours)

As I wrote there,

> I've written a query to identify votes that were overlooked because of these flaws, and am currently running it against past voting data; 192 users were affected, most by only a few votes but some by hundreds - those people greatly affected by this I've sent messages in preparation for some consternation.

The "unaccepts" are an artifact of the system not differentiating between normal votes and "accept" votes.

Sorry for the inconvenience; I'm afraid the tooling currently available doesn't make these corrections particularly smooth to roll out. Should all be wrapped up in about an hour.

Comment: It is OK. It is a generally good job to stop serial upvoting. But now it looks like an overkill for me.

Comment: And please take in account that at AU there are not too many people who write many good answers. And upvoting each other is not always cheating. I could upvote someone like A.B., Fabby, etc many times. But it is not personal at all. I upvoted Oli many times too, but that seems to be OK.

Comment: And to be fair I downvoted the above mentioned people too ;-)

Comment: Hard not to look like overkill when year(s) of corrections all get made in the span of a few hours I'm afraid. BTW, I didn't ignore downvotes with this - there are equivalent systems with equivalent flaws for serial downvoting, and votes missed there are being corrected as well.

Comment: For instance I upvoted many posts by a few users. But I downvoted some other posts of the same users. Does not that mean that this voting is not personal. I agree that it is hard too code 100% fairly.

Comment: Being fair is impossible, but at least we can be objective - hence a system based on patterns.

Comment: It is OK for me. But some people may get really pxxxed off.

Comment: Is it supposed to as well undo down-votes? This what happened to me i see a down-vote I done being undone and i only down-votes the answer and the question of someone down who had not a very good sportsmanship. I think this should not happen...

Comment: Yes, @Videonauth: downvoting posts because of their author is just as discouraged as upvoting posts because of their author. Vote according to the quality and usefulness of the post, not your opinion of who wrote it. See also: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3248/serial-downvoting-reversed

Comment: I'm not even talking about serial down-voting, I'm talking about a user who in fact first up-voted me, then decided to put an own answer forward and retracted his up-vote. Left me with finally deleting my answer and leaving him for this single question and answer a down-vote. Such behavior should not be encouraged at all I believe. But well then so be it. But if your script counts two down-votes given on an answer and a question in short time already as serial it does not feel right and you should probably be back at the drawing board and check that algorithm.Its just my two cents.

Comment: @Videonauth You described exactly what we don't want - downvotes because someone removed their upvote. This system seems to work well.

Comment: @Tim you are entitled to your believe and viewpoint, but I'm still saying that measurement is to close, we are all humans, i spend a while searching for an answer just to get copied from the OP, well makes me angry as it would do to anyone else. And if a system narrows down onto finding two votes out of millions, the algorithm is not right. :) Note: I'm fine with the whole process itself. Just pointing out this may be flawed to a point that a regular use of that algorithm is not of use.

Comment: OK, this has been really bothering me today that I lost 70 points on this.  First of all, I had no idea what "serial voting" was in the first place.  Secondly, how were we supposed to know that we were victims to it?  Thirdly, I have written good quality posts where the OP thanked me for helping them and I was correct on my answer, but this system took my upvote from the OP away and it was legit.

Comment: @Shog9 «downvoting posts because of their author is just as discouraged» I actually got downvotes for exactly this reason on two different sites of the network. I contacted support but got no response at all.

Comment: I don't know whether to be happy or sad that no one liked me enough to serially vote for my posts.

Comment: You should review your algorithm: talk to @Oli or read the reply to your post...  **;-)**

Comment: You know part of the story here, @fabby. I've spent a fair bit of time looking at the rest.